# Angle between $n + 1$ equidistant unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

My question is basically as posed in the title. Suppose we are given $n + 1$ unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ so that the angle between any pair of them is the same. What is that angle? I have (unfounded) reason to believe that the angle is arccos$(\frac{-1}{n})$, but I don't know how to prove it. For example, we can find three unit vectors $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} \frac{-1}{2} \\ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} \frac{-1}{2} \\ \frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}\end{pmatrix}$, and the angle between any pair of them is arccos$(\frac{-1}{2})$, since the dot product of any pair of them is $\frac{-1}{2}$. Can anyone supply the reasoning for general $\mathbb{R}^n$, or correct me if I'm incorrect?

Comment: See [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Cartesian_coordinates_for_regular_n-dimensional_simplex_in_Rn)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since they're spaced symmetrically,

$$u_1+u_2+u_3+\cdots+u_n+u_{n+1}=0.$$

Now take the dot product with $u_1$:

$$1+u_1\cdot u_2+u_1\cdot u_3+\cdots+u_1\cdot u_n+u_1\cdot u_{n+1}=0.$$

Again by symmetry, these last $n$ dot products should be the same:

$$1+u_1\cdot u_2+u_1\cdot u_2+\cdots+u_1\cdot u_2+u_1\cdot u_2=0$$

$$1+nu_1\cdot u_2=0$$

$$u_1\cdot u_2=-1/n.$$

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is the definition of being 'spaced symmetrically' that $u_1 + \cdots + u_n + u_{n+1} = 0$, assuming they are all the same length?

Comment: I don't have a definition of "spaced symmetrically". I don't intend this to be a proof, but rather an argument that the formula is reasonable. Indeed, we can have $n+1$ vectors in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ that have equal angles but don't sum to $0$; I haven't used the dimension restriction.

Comment: It's a beautiful argument!

Comment: Hm ok that's a little surprising at a glance. Thanks again for your helpful answer!

Answer (score 4):

To fill a gap in mr_e_man's beautiful argument, we prove the following claim . . .

**Claim:**$\;$If $v_1,...,v_{n+1}$ are distinct unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that all the dot products $v_i{\,\cdot\,}v_j$ with $i\ne j$ are equal, then 
$$\;v_1+\cdots +v_{n+1}=0$$
**Proof:**

Let $c$ be the common value of those dot products.

From $v_1\ne v_2$, it follows that $c\ne1$.

Since $v_1,...,v_{n+1}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, it follows that $v_1,...,v_{n+1}$ are linearly dependent.

Thus$\;a_1v_1+\cdots a_{n+1}v_{n+1}\!=0\;$for some $a_1,...,a_{n+1}\in\mathbb{R}$, not all zero.

Without loss of generality, assume $a_1\ne 0$.

Let $A=a_1+\cdots+ a_{n+1}$.

Fix $k\in\{1,...,n+1\}$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&
a_1v_1+\cdots a_{n+1}v_{n+1}=0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
v_k{\,\cdot\,}(a_1v_1+\cdots a_{n+1}v_{n+1})=0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
a_k+(A-a_k)c=0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
a_k=\frac{Ac}{c-1}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
a_1=\cdots=a_{n+1}\\[12pt]
\text{hence}\;\;&
a_1v_1+\cdots a_{n+1}v_{n+1}=0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
a_1(v_1+\cdots +v_{n+1})=0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
v_1+\cdots +v_{n+1}=0\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much for adding this supplementary detail. This entire argument is really clean and helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Build an $n\times(n+1)$ matrix $A$ by letting the $k$-th column be your $k$-th vector.
Consider the matrix $B=A^tA$ where $A^t$ is the transpose of $A$. Then $B$ has
size $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ and must be singular, as its rank is at most the rank
of $A$, which is $\le n$.

The $(j,k)$ entry of $B$ is the dot-product of your $j$-th and $k$-th vectors. This
is $1$ when $j=k$ and $x$ when $j\ne k$ where $x$ is the cosine of the angle you
seek. Thus
$$0=\det B=\det\pmatrix{1&x&x&\cdots &x\\
x&1&x&\cdots &x\\
x&x&1&\cdots &x\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
x&x&x&\cdots&1}.$$
It's a routine calcutaion to get
$$\det(B)=(nx+1)(1-x)^n$$
so $x=1$ or $x=-1/n$, and we can rule out $x=1$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I do see that this implies the desired result, but unfortunately I don't think I see why the determinant calculation is routine. I assume the symmetry plays a role in simplifying the calculation, but I still don't see how to perform this besides the straightforward recursive computation. Is there an easier way to see this?

Comment: One can just use row operations. @t42d

Comment: I see. Thanks again!

Comment: @t42d The matrix is a rank-$1$ update of a multiple of the identity matrix, so we can compute its determinant efficiently using the Matrix Determinant Lemma.

Comment: @TravisWillse thanks for introducing me to that! Very convenient for this situation.